# is it possible to import multiple mongo collection using single mongo-river meta in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am trying to import multiple collection from mongodb to elasticsearch and join them , lets say if join is not possible at least I want specific fields from some mongo collections to river in to elasticsearch using single river meta?

tried below meta , doesn't work.

```
PUT _river/mongodbicslicense/_meta
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      {
        "host": "abc",
        "port": "27017"
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "skip_initial_import": false
      "include_collection": [
        "abc",
        "xyz"
      ],
      "include_fields": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "X",
        "Z"
      ]
    },
    "db": "datadb",
    "gridfs": false,
    "credentials": [
      {
        "db": "datadb",
        "user": "me",
        "password": "mypass"
      }
    ]
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "frommongoindex",
    "type": "abcd"
  }
}
```

exploring mongo , need help ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to import multiple mongo collections using single river.
Elasticsearch-river-mongodb creates a new river for each MongoDB collection that should be indexed by Elasticsearch.